# What is it that makes sound in Linux so harder than Windows?

Tags: linux, drivers, windows, audio, debian-installer

Im a Debian user but posting here anyway.

Since earlier versions of Windows sound just works, even drivers wasn't necessary to install to a basic sound input/output, you just install Windows and microphone just works and integrate with Skype.

To make Skype/microphone works on Linux is a WAR, its so complicated to do something Windows did effortless more than 20 years ago and we are on 2020.

Some telling its because there is plenty of choices on Linux and you need to choose between then but many people just want it works on basic level, that is a headphone and microphone that just works

Even PulseAudioVolumeControl is better than VolumeControl on Windows its useless since audio doesnt works on my Lenovo E431.

If there is plenty of choices just make the installer choose the most basic default and let sound experts tweek it too.

There is almost same question that was closed that is more than 10 years old, as you can see its not a new issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/9ai50/dear_reddit_what_is_it_that_makes_sound_in_linux/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For new computers having the most recent Linux kernel installed is the key, so using Debian which features quite an old kernel might lead to sound issues.

This can be easily explained by the fact that the Linux kernel is monolithic and doesn't have any [resemblance of stable API/ABI](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/process/stable-api-nonsense.html#stable-api-nonsense), thus **new drivers mean a new kernel**. RedHat does backport certain drivers (mostly storage and network) but other than that their kernel has the same issue. A lot of people are not content with this situation but it's unlikely to change/improve any time soon or ever.

There's a chance if Google's Fuschia/Zircon kernel takes off and becomes a real threat to the Linux kernel, the latter might change its development model.

---

Here's another issue which affect Linux distros in general: whereas in Windows and MacOS X the core system components are tightly interconnected which means efficiency, performance and lower power consumption, Pulse Audio in Linux is a 100% user space application which uses a ton of hacks (real time priority via [capabilities](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Capabilities)) and tricks to get the most from the Linux kernel ALSA APIs.

Comment: A friend of me uses the "Liquorix Kernel" but i think is better just go to Windows, would be great if it just works. On net cards there is the Ethernet as default, audio should have a minimal spec to a generic drive too.

Comment: It's amazing how people downvote the status quo of the desktop Linux. Truly atrocious. There was no "opinion" in the answer - **I described how Linux is being developed**. Damn.